# cannot debug Webpack 3 index.ts with node-ts in vscode

Tags: typescript, debugging, webpack-3, ts-node

I am using vs code and I am trying to debug my index.ts file and I am building my ts files with ts-node.  My issue is when I start debugging I get an error because of my index.ts file contains

```
import './index.scss';
```

the error is `$mainColor: #7777bb; SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

my launch.json looks like:

```
    {
        "name": "Current TS File",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "args": [
            "${relativeFile}"
        ],
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy",
            "-r",
            "ts-node/register"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "protocol": "inspector"
    }
```

this makes perfect sense considering this is invalid typescript/javascript syntax. Also,  I've come to the conclusion that excluding this import is bad practice when bundling with webpack 3(2). my problem is I am trying to find out how to properly debug with ts-node and somehow skip this import statement or if there is a reliable way to bundle my SCSS files without importing them into my index.ts (I know this is contradictory but if it works...).  I also want to avoid debugging through the browser if that's possible.